# How can I pass a string from View to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
public ActionResult Message()
{
    chartstype chartname = new chartstype();
    List<chartstype> listchart = new List<chartstype>();
    chartname.charttype = "Column";
    listchart.Add(chartname);
    TempData["name"] =listchart;
    TempData.Keep();
    return View();
}
```

And I want to change my code to be able to pass a string to chartname.charttype variable from View.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn the very basics of your technology before posting questions to this site.

Comment: Post the view code as well

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

you could change (or overload) the ActionMethods signature to take a string Parameter

like...

```
public ActionResult Message(String someVariable)
    {
        //do something with the contents of someVariable
        chartstype chartname = new chartstype();
        List<chartstype> listchart = new List<chartstype>();
        chartname.charttype = "Column";
        listchart.Add(chartname);
        TempData["name"] =listchart;
        TempData.Keep();
        return View();
    }
```

which could be called like `https://www.example.com/Message?someVariable=someString`

Comment: I knew this method. But I have to write the types in the View code to be able to be able to call for all types. So, my all task is to make different types of chart in the same View. And I can't do to call like that. This is my problem. Can I skip this call method?

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what you try to say

Answer (score 0):

**In controller**

```
        public ActionResult Message(String chartName)
        {
            chartstype chartname = new chartstype();
            List<chartstype> listchart = new List<chartstype>();
            chartname.charttype = chartName;
            listchart.Add(chartname);
            TempData["name"] =listchart;
            TempData.Keep();
            return View();
        }
```

**URL :https://www.example.com/Message?chartName=ABCD**

Answer (score 0):

```
   public ActionResult Message(string message)
```

and make sure to see if string is null, because anyone can call this method trough url.

```
  if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message))
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
```

And then code in view

```
<form action="/controlerName/Message"  method="get or post , get is by default if you don't put this atribute">
<input id="txt1" type="text" name="message" value="set value here or in JS or let user enter value"/>
```

If you don't want textbox to be seen use

`<input type="hidden" name="message" value="somevalue"/>`
Unless you want to call your method from javaScript using ajax?